# Are there any other English syllables without vowels, besides "thm"?

Tags: etymology, orthography, vowels, syllables

As far as I *knew*<sup>*</sup>, all English syllables have a vowel sound and all of them are spelled accordingly, except for "thm" as in **rhythm** and **algorithm**.  Are there any others?  And are there any etymological reasons why this / they exist(s)?

<sub>* See JSBang's answer.</sub>

Comment: ***’n’*** [   ](http://127.0.0.1/)

Comment: @F'x Similarly, _nth_, as in the _nth degree_.

Comment: @F'x Can you give an example?

Comment: @HaL I wouldn't count that as a valid part of English, personally.

Comment: @Matthew Read *nth* is a valid word in Scrabble, so...

Comment: @Jack I know ... I hate the Scrabble dictionary :P

Comment: @Matthew: *rock **’n’** roll*

Comment: @F'x Yeah, I personally wouldn't count that either.  Thanks though!

Comment: *nth* does have a vowel sound, though.

Comment: @Matthew: [nth is in a bunch of dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=nth&ls=a)

Comment: @Matthew - We've eschewed the Scrabble dictionary. A tip: Don't try to play with the OED.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Occasionally *-sm* does the same thing: **chasm**, **schism**, etc. As I pronounce them, these are all two-syllable words.

Having said that, I would question your premise that "all English syllables have a vowel sound". There are in fact a great many English syllables which don't have any vowel sound at all (in most US English dialects, as discussed below), but rather have a [syllabic consonant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant):

> button
>
> tanner
>
> pickle

The second syllable of all of these words, though spelled with a vowel, is typically pronounced with no vowel sound at all between the medial consonant and the final consonant. Instead, the final consonant is elongated into a syllable of its own. In *pickle*, for example, there is no vowel, not even a schwa, between the [k] and the [l]. As soon as the [k] is released the lateral contact on the [l] begins, and the [l] sound is drawn out for the full length of an unstressed syllable. In my dialect, at least, all words ending with an unstressed syllable containing [n], [r], or [l] are pronounced this way.

Different dialects handle this differently, however. In British English, for example, *tanner* often has a final shwa and no [r] sound at all, and the handling of unstressed final [n] as in *button* varies quite a bit even within North America.

Comment: To avoid confusing international visitors to the site, it's probably worth adding "in US English" (or some suitable similar qualifier) to "is typically pronounced with no vowel sound" - to me *button* has a schwa, and *tanner* doesn't even have a final consonant :-)

Comment: Hmm, in my dialect `pickle` is the only one.  Strange ... I really thought this didn't happen!

Comment: @psmears: Why in the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/button) it says the opposite of what you say? I mean, the BrE pronunciation there is [ˈbʌtn] and not [ˈbʌtən]...

Comment: @psmears: I've actually studied (informally) how various dictionary treat syllabic consonants in their pronunciation guides and there is great variety. Some indicate a schwa, some indicate nothing at all, and a few put a dot below the syllabic consonant. Some dictionaries are not even self-consistent.

Comment: @Alenanno: The Cambridge dictionary has it with an [optional schwa](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/button_1). @Alenanno, @hippietrail: The differences in the dictionaries likely reflect the slight differences in pronunciation among speakers, and the fact that the difference in pronunciation between a very short schwa vowel and a syllabic consonant is minimal.

Comment: @psmears, @Alenanno: for me, *button* is actually [ˈbʌʔn], and I believe that the glottalization of the *t* and the syllabic *n* are complementary features. That is, people who pronounce the *t* as [ʔ] usually also make the [n] syllabic, which people who keep the *t* as [t] will have a schwa. However, I kept discussion of glottalization out of the main answer to avoid confusing things too much.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know of any satisfying answer aside from JSBձոգչ’s [*-sm* as in *chasm*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24007/77227). But, here are some probably unsatisfying ones with resononants that are (possibly) syllabic but don't have any written vowel letters corresponding to their syllable.

### Words with an ambiguous number of syllables

This depends a lot on your accent, but for many people at least some of the following words are disyllabic, with the second syllable composed only of syllabic “l”: *snar**l**, oi**l**, ow**l**, pear**l**.* (For me, the first two seem a lot like they have two syllables, while the last two seem more like monosyllables or at most sesquisyllables.)

Likewise, with possibly syllabic “r”, we have *choi**r**, coi**r**, hou**r**.*

But speakers’ intuitions about these words vary wildly: see "[Why the extra syllable in words like these ending in -r and -l?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235508/why-the-extra-syllable-in-words-like-these-ending-in-r)" and "[How many syllables are in the word 'hour'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80224/how-many)", as well as the paper "[Sesquisyllables of English: The structure of vowel-liquid syllables](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/icphs-proceedings/ICPhS1999/papers/p14_0109.pdf)" by Lisa M. Lavoie and Abigail C. Cohn).

### Relatively well-established loanwords that use non-English spelling conventions

syllabic “l”: *dirnd**l*** (from a Germanic language), *axolot**l*** and various other loanwords from Nahuatl with *-tl*, as [going mentioned](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24043/77227)

Answer (score 1):

How about those containing a y?

For example:

- party
- many
- patchy
- syzygy
- xylophone

They have a vowel sound, but are not "spelled accordingly"

There are also some obscure words like axolotl and dirndl. [From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_without_vowels) there is also crwth and cwm.

Comment: "y" is sometimes a vowel; at minimum, anyways, there's something there to indicate a vowel sound.  Good point about axolotl etc. though.

Comment: No. There are at least two English vowels (using the definition broadened to relate to symbols) rarely taught to schoolkids, y as in these examples, and w in the lexicalised cwm, cwrth.