# How many syllables are in the word 'hour'?

Tags: syllables, diphthongs, rhoticity

Does the word 'hour' have 1 or 2 syllables?

Comment: It has to have two: see [my doggerel below](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80230/2085) for why.

Comment: @tchrist: not in all varieties of English.

Comment: See also: [How many syllables in the word fire](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36097/how-many-syllables-are-there-in-the-word-fire)? For me: two syllables in *hour* by itself, two syllables total in *hourly*.

Comment: About one and a half; diphthongs are hard. :-)

Comment: Much as I hate to say something completely useless, the only correct answer is "it depends how you pronounce it".

Comment: Professor Wells talks about it in this blog post http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/12/triphthongs-anyone.html

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/607404/2085).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what I understand, *hour, fire, hire, layer, rhythm*, etc., are all examples of words which are not easily classifiable. But, according to [this linguist](http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2009/06/how-many-syllables-in-hour.html),

> Hour and fire are generally considered to be **monosyllabic** words containing a **triphthong**.

Wikipedia further confirms this in a couple of its articles.

[Triphthong (WP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphthong#First_segment_is_the_nucleus):

> English in British Received Pronunciation (**monosyllabic triphthongs with R** are optionally distinguished from sequences with disyllabic realizations)
>
> **[aʊ̯ə̯] as in hour** (compare with disyllabic "plougher" [aʊ̯.ə])

(British) [Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation#Vowels):

> **RP also possesses the triphthongs /aɪə/ as in ire, /aʊə/ as in hour**, /əʊə/ as in lower, /eɪə/ as in layer and /ɔɪə/ as in loyal. There are different possible realisations of these items: in slow, careful speech they may be pronounced as a two-syllable triphthong with three distinct vowel qualities in succession, or as a monosyllabic triphthong. In more casual speech the middle vowel may be considerably reduced, by a process known as smoothing, and in an extreme form of this process the triphthong may even be reduced to a single vowel, though this is rare, and almost never found in the case of /ɔɪə/[47] . In such a case the difference between /aʊə/, /aɪə/, and /ɑː/ may be neutralised with all three units realised as [ɑː] or [äː].

All that said, I suspect that the most accurate answer ultimately depends on how you pronounce it yourself. Nice question :)

Comment: Just because you have three vowels in a row does not mean you have a triphthong.  Somehow the UK people count `/ə/` as a glide, but it isn’t.  Words like *wow*, *yow*, *why*, and *yay* are actual triphthongs, because you have a glide to either side of the principal/syllabic vowel.

Comment: @PeterShor In BrE (always depending on dialect and region), *layer/player* have two syllables with *ay* as a diphthong; and *lair* is a monosyllabic diphthong. [IPA is difficult on an iPad, sorry]

Answer (score 11):

Not that everything I learned in school was true, but I remember being taught that most dictionaries – at least print dictionaries – broke words into syllables, and this was one of those things that dictionaries were useful for.

So, one could always count the number of •'s, and add one, and get the number of syllables in a word:

[image]

One dictionary's own definition of *syllable* mentions there are three in *inferno*, and two in *water*; as could be expected, the entries for those words show them being broken up that way. By the same token, the word *word* has one:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, this method for counting syllables creates a few anomalies, whereby some one- and two-syllable words are pronounced very much alike (in other words, hearing the two words would lead someone to think they have the same number of syllables, but the dictionary would indicate otherwise):

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

(The oddest of all might be *hire* and *higher*, which I would pronounce as true heterographs, but the dictionary would break into one and two syllables, respectively.)

I found it interesting that the word *syllabification* was defined as *the division of words into syllables, either in speech or in writing*. That "either in speech or in writing" part made me wonder if one could accurately say that the word *hour* has one syllable in writing, and two in speech – that is, if *hour* was pronounced as rhyming with *tower* or *power*, and not as a heterograph with *are*, as some drawlers might be inclined to do.

In the end, I sup•pose it all de•pends on how you de•fine syl•la•ble, and how you de•cide to come up with an of•fi•cial an•swer in ca•ses where the ex•act num•ber of syl•la•bles is not im•me•di•ate•ly ev•i•dent or ap•par•ent.

Comment: It seems like dictionaries are using an *orthographic* syllabification, which is largely based on spelling and etymology rather than phonology. (For example, double consonant letters like in *inner* get split, and the dictionary syllabification avoids splitting up *-tion* even though under Wells's analysis the /ʃ/ should go with the preceding syllable.) Here *fire* is a unitary morpheme and  *dryer* contains a morpheme boundary; hence the distinction given, despite there being no difference in pronunciation (at least in many AmE speakers).

Comment: The dots show how to hyphenate, not how to pronounce the words. In some cases, syllables can't be separated with a hyphen (e.g., because they are too short to stand alone).

Comment: @Bradd - True. Usually there is a strong correspondence between hyphenation marks and syllable counts, but there are some notable exceptions. I don't believe there's any schism in how we regard this matter.

Answer (score 3):

> *People who are born to power
>
>   Lack the time to spare an hour
>
>   Smelling rose or other flower,
>
>   Be it sweet or be it sour.*

Since those lines of trochaic tetrameter all rhyme with each other on the last foot, *hour* needs must contain two syllables.  The stanza is 8/8/8/8 by syllables, with rhyme scheme AAAA.

Here is a different illustration of the same thing:

> *Tapered candles need no power,
>
>   ‭    ‭    flicker though they may.
>
>   They will burn for just an hour,
>
>   ‭    ‭    turning night to day.*

That one has an 8/5/8/5 syllable pattern and an ABAB rhyme scheme. Unless *power* and *hour* rhyme, and are each two syllables, that doesn’t work.

Comment: Are you serious here? They also rhyme as if *power, hour, flower* and *sour* are all just one syllable. And if *power* and *flower* are two syllables, and *hour* and *sour* are one syllable, then you get an ABAB rhyme scheme.

Comment: Counter-example: *O thou, my lovely boy, who in thy pow’r* / *Dost hold time’s fickle glass his sickle hour*, among many other examples. If both *power* and *hour* are the same length, there should be no need to shorten *power* to *pow'r*.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I’m serious: all lines have 8 syllables, and it is AAAA rhyme, not ABAB rhyme. Don’t let spelling confuse matters, because I could rearrange lines so that dissimilar spellings align, and it will still rhyme. Any child in the Midwest will tell you that *hour* and *power* rhyme.

Comment: Just to return to this briefly, if you think ‘hour’ has two syllables, you have to assume the consonant /w/ in the middle. So, something like /aʊwə(r)/. The answer may well be that it’s one syllable in British English and two in American English and perhaps other dialects.

Comment: @choster puts his finger on it. English poets have always felt free to treat these words as either monosyllabic or disyllabic according to metrical exigencies. Shakespeare, for instance, in [*WT*](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=winterstale&keyword1=hour&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr): of six uses in verse, two are monosyllabic, two disyllabic, and two ambiguous.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Why do we have to assume that?

Comment: @ymar: When one syllable follows another, doesn't one of them have to contain a consonant? That, at least, is usually the case.

Comment: @Barrie I don't think it does. I'm not a specialist, but John Wells seems to think otherwise. (There's a link to his blog somewhere on this page.)

Comment: @ymar: ‘Attempts have been made at defining the syllable in terms of everything from muscular contractions to perceived peaks of loudness, but so far no definition has proved satisfactory.’ R L Trask in ‘Language and Linguistics: The Key Concepts’.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Well, that's what's said on the linked page too. And in other sources. At least I believe there's no accepted *phonetic* definition.

Comment: Maybe in British English, when one syllable follows another, one of them has to contain a consonant, like @Barrie says. This certainly isn't true in American English. We pronounce *drawing* with no consonant between the two syllables (no *drawring* allowed here, except in Boston and NYC). And the French don't have this constraint either.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Well, once again, it depends how you define 'syllable'. You could say that if any one vowel sound follows another without an intervening consonant, then those sounds must be interpreted as diphthongs or triphthongs within a single syllable, rather than as elements in separate syllables.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Sometimes two adjacent vowels can be in hiatus not diphthong, casting each to its own syllable. I doubt even you would consider a word like *neon* or *chaos* to contain a diphthong.  Both those words have two syllables in English by any analysis I am familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

IPA isn't that difficult to decipher, is it?

> **[hour](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hour?region=us&q=hour)**  /ou(ə)r/ (one syllable)
>
> **[hour](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hour?s=t)** /aʊər, ˈaʊər/ (one or two syllables, one being preferred)

Comment: But doesn't /ou(ə)r/ mean /our/ (one syllable) or /ouər/ (two syllables), since English does not have an /ouə/ triphthong (well ... I guess some dialects might, but I don't think the *Oxford English dictionaries* count /ouə/ as a triphthong in AmE).

Comment: @PeterShor According to the [Virtual Linguist](http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2009/06/how-many-syllables-in-hour.html), _hour_ is "generally considered to be monosyllabic word containing a triphthong." Then again, I always think of the commercial ditty "Hour after hour, pucker power."

Comment: The *Virtual Linguist* speaks BrE. I was objecting to your decoding of the non-IPA pronunciation symbols used by the *online Oxford Dictionaries* for AmE. They don't always indicate syllables in their phonetic encoding; see [catalyst](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/catalyst?region=us&q=catalyst), which is definitely three syllables, even though they only indicate two, and [different](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/different?region=us&q=different), which can be either two or three.

Comment: It can’t be a triphthong.  They are somehow defining a triphthong as nothing other than three vowels sounds in a row, **syllables notwithstanding.**  That isn’t right! A diphthong is a main syllabic vowel with a glide, either /w/ or /j/, attached to it on one side or the other.  A triphthong has a non-syllabic glide on both sides of it.  Schwa is not a glide: it creates a new syllable because it is in hiatus.  Words like *yay* and *wow* are triphthongs, but words like *Maya*, *power*, and *cayenne* are not triphthongs.  It has to all be in one syllable, and those vowels are not.

Comment: @tchrist [John Wells](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/12/triphthongs-anyone.html) would agree with you. I'm of two minds (if not two syllables) about it, since I pronounce it with 1 syllable, but have the aformentioned "Hour after hour" ditty in my head.

Comment: Somehow the Brits are using a different notion of triphthong than one is taught in linguistics, and in studying other languages.  I believe Wells is correct.

Comment: @tchrist, I don't know what you consider "the" authority on the meaning of linguistic terms to be, but *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics, 5th ed.*, D. Crystal, 2003, defines a diphthong as *A term used in the phonetic classification of vowel sounds on the basis of their manner of articulation: it refers to a vowel where there is a single (perceptual) noticeable change of quality during a syllable, as in English beer, time, loud*. I don't see any restriction to /w/ or /j/ there.

Comment: I don't know the reasons behind the linguistic definition of *triphthong* is, but I would say that if a speaker perceives *hour* as one syllable, and pronounces all three vowel components aʊə, it's a pretty good argument for calling it a triphthong.

Answer (score 2):

I would pronounce this with two syllables:

Ow - Err

Ymmv

Answer (score 1):

As long as "ou" is a diphthong, this word has one syllable.

Comment: More descriptive than helpful. If there's only one (dipthong) vowel, of course there's only one syllable. But is that always true? What about *our*?

Comment: How can you make [my doggerel](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80230/2085) scan if *our* has just one syllable?

Comment: @tchrist First, there's no reason for your doggerel to scan. How can your doggerel be proof? Second, it's easy to make your doggerel scan with "our" having just one syllable. Just pronounce "sour" as a one-syllable word, and you get an ABAB. Or pronounce all four final words as one-syllable words, and you get an AAAA again. All possiblities are valid. Just listen to the last stanza [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AffwMHJqulg) (3:30).

Comment: Not true. For me, yes, "ou" is a diphthong, *but the /r/ is syllabic*.