# Does 'rhythm' have one or two syllables?

Tags: phonology, syllables

Does the word 'rhythm' have one or two syllables?

I'm wondering if there are any reasons for or against a sound-based argument vs a written-based argument.

Comment: Syllables are a vocal property of language. A dictionary will tell you the prevailing pronunciation has two syllables. There is nothing about the spelling that has to do with syllable count.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80224/how-many-syllables-are-in-the-word-hour   
Odd how this question is on the verge of closure, but a [related one asked last year](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80224) has **27** upvotes and no close votes. I could understand close votes being cast because of duplication, but they are being cast as "off-topic". Say what?

Comment: @J.R. I think close-votes for duplication and off-topic would both be equally as likely for the simple fact that I had no idea how to articulate such a question (and thus couldn't search for it, or coerce it into a strong fit for stackexchange). That 'related' question is exactly what I was after, however. Thanks!

Comment: In retrospect, I regret my general reference close vote, because it's easy to draw incorrect conclusions about syllabification from a dictionary.

Comment: Following the chain of comments I'm marking this as a dupe instead.

Comment: In my opinion the spelling of *rhythm* does not look like it could be pronounced with only one syllable - is there a way to pronounce *r* and *th* and *m* and *not* get two syllables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may appear from spelling that *rhythm* has only one syllable, because it has only one vowel. However, the M is a [**syllabic consonant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant) which forms a syllable of its own. [Sonorant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonorant) consonants like L, M, N, and R can act as the nucleus of a syllable just as a vowel can (although English dictionaries often insert a schwa to represent the nucleus).

Comment: This seems as a duplicate answer.

Comment: I'm puzzled as to how this seems like a duplicate of the other answer. We reached the same conclusion but otherwise posted entirely different information. My answer addresses **why** the word has two syllables despite a spelling that might suggest otherwise, with additional information about the nature of syllables themselves.

Comment: @Tom Just because there's already a correct answer doesn't mean there couldn't be a better one.  I'm glad OP accepted the more informative answer, rather than just the answer with the most upvotes *(aka. the first answer)*; it seems like most askers don't.

Comment: It depends on one's definition of "syllable" – many dictionaries show words like _rhythm_ and _fire_ as having one syllable, not two. Personally, I'd answer [_one_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80224/how-many-syllables-are-in-the-word-hour/80293#80293), not _two_, irrespective of the vowel count, but I wouldn't argue that two is 'wrong' – my ears wouldn't permit that.

Comment: Do you have an example of a dictionary listing _rhythm_ as a one-syllable word? Words like _fire_ certainly can be pronounced with one syllable or two, depending on whether you merge the R into the coda or pronounce it syllabically, but I cannot imagine merging the M of _rhythm_ into the coda of the first syllable.

Comment: Bradd, For some reason, [dictionaries](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0kiM7.png) don't list "rhythm" as "rhyth•m" or "rhy•thm" in the same way they list "meter" as "me•ter". I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm just saying that I think the O.P.'s inquiry about "a sound-based argument vs a written-based argument" is very interesting, and not easily answerable using commonly-available references.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Those "syllable" dots are for hyphenation, not for pronunciation. _Rhythm_ can't be hyphenated because the second syllable is only one letter, and English conventions don't permit that. Note that the pronunciation includes a schwa before the syllabic M, which is how the dictionary indicates it's a separate syllable.

Comment: @Bradd - As I said, it depends on how one elects to define "syllable". As [one website](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-hyphens-in-your-writing.html) says: _Place the hyphen between the syllables, or sounds, of a word. (If you’re not sure where the syllable breaks are in a word, check the dictionary.)_ By the way, I'm not arguing, I'm agreeing. Your can't-hyphenate-only-one-letter rule probably explains why [some](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agreeable) dictionaries show a dot in _a·gree_, and [some](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agreeable) don't.

Answer (score 8):

It has two syllables.  Syllables are entirely features of pronunciation, not of writing, so written-based arguments are irrelevant.

Comment: Indeed, "Worcestershire" looks like it has five syllables, based on orthography.

Comment: Carrying an argument too far may not be advisable in most cases. See also: answer by Bradd Szonye

Comment: @Kaz - "Worcestershire" can look also like it has three, depending on [where you look](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/worcestershire).

Comment: @J.R. Sure, if you don't look at the two places where two syllables are hiding, then all you see is three. :)

Comment: My favourite is the English name *Cholmondley* (pronounced *Chumley*).