# Why the extra syllable in words like these ending in -r and -l?

Tags: pronunciation

First-off, I'm not a native speaker.

I've noticed that a lot of words ending in -r and -l are pronounced as if they had an extra syllable. Especially when they have a -ee- or -ai- sound.

Consider

> - reap
> - real
> - rear

The last two are pronounced ree-ul and ree-ur. Reap is a one-syllable word. Others aren't.

More examples: beep/beer, cake/care, laid/lair

Also, words with most other sounds preceding -r don't seem to follow the pattern. Car is not caa-ur. More is not mo-ur.

So my questions are:

1. Is the extra syllable just something I'm hearing, or is it actually pronounced?
2. If it is pronounced, why do only -r and -l follow the rule?

Comment: It depends on your dialect; *more* is two syllables if you speak with a classic Boston accent. But you're probably asking about British accents.

Comment: @PeterShor: Is it? Hmm... The plot thickens.

Comment: What you're hearing is probably the diphthong inserted in those words by certain speakers. It amounts to an extra syllable that "shouldn't" be there. Some dialects feature this production. You'll hear it in other words as well: *bayuck* for back, etc.

Comment: Sorry @Robusto, but an extra syllable in *back* to make it sound like *bayuck*, is not the same thing as the 2-syllable *rear* or *peel* which even "accent-neutral" US Midwesterners pronounce with two syllables.  I think the OP is onto something here and hope there are some informative answers.

Comment: Well, I guess we'll just have to wait for @JohnLawler then. ^_^

Comment: I live in the U.S. Midwest, and I've never heard anyone pronounce _rear_ or _peel_ with more than one syllable.

Comment: @Nicole - listen to the pronunciation link on this site and count the sounds...there are 2 sounds to *peel*: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/peel

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Thanks for the support. I'm surprised that some people don't agree there are two sounds.

Comment: @Tushar To paraphrase an old joke, ask five English-speakers about the pronunciation of their own language, and you'll get six opinions.

Comment: I have an old [1950s], very large British English dictionary with near-IPA guides, and it tells me that 'peel' is pronounced /pi:əl/ rather than what I'd expect, /pi:l/

Comment: @DavidGarner: I guess you just proved your earlier comment right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the extra syllable is there.  Like most such changes, it happens in order to simplify the pronunciation.  The English long/tense vowels are diphthongs -- they end in a glide -y or -w, so when a diphthong is followed by a -l or -r in the same syllable, you're left with syllables ending in -yl, -wl, -yr, -wr, which are hard to pronounce.

In my speech, which is a Midwestern variety of Standard English, what happens to simplify the pronunciation is that either the -l or -r becomes syllabic, so you get an extra syllable (as you've observed), or else the glide -y or -w drops out, and you're left with a simple vowel preceding the -l or -r instead of a diphthong.

Personally, I make the -l syllabic in your example "real": [ɹɪjl] ==> [ɹɪj.l̩], but in "rear", instead the glide is dropped: [ɹɪjɹ] ==> [ɹɪɹ].  However, I believe syllabifying the -r and leaving the glide is also common.

I also drop the glide, making the preceding vowel a monophthong in your examples "beer", "care", and "lair", but again, I think the two syllable pronunciations are common.

Comment: This is the right answer. I think it happens (in some dialect) for nearly all the diphthongs in English followed by /r/ or /l/.

Comment: @Greg Lee: Thanks. Helpful answer. But it's surprising that -r and -l are considered difficult to pronounce. I'm from India. In Hindi/Urdu, -r is treated as any other consonant and pronounced without the glide. Without that, our poetry would look very different. Meter is essential in Indian poetry and a disproportionate number of words end in -r.

Comment: No, this is the wrong answer. As per the dictionary definition of a diphthong (see my answer) it is a "gliding speech sound [...] held to be a single sound". It is hence one syllable and NOT two.

Comment: @Tushar, it's the syllable final combinations -wr and -yr which, I say, are difficult.  Not just r.

Comment: @AndyT, if the glide part of a diphthong is syllabified, it's true, then it's no longer a diphthong.  But you can't reach a conclusion about the actual pronunciation just from a definition.  If, after syllabifying, there is no longer a diphthong, we won't call it one.  Does that solve the problem for you?

Comment: @Greg - That doesn't solve my problem, no... but I now understand your point better. I'm now confused and unsure as to whether a diphthong can be pronounced as two syllables instead of a diphthong, but I can at least understand it as a point of view.

Comment: And apparently I can't now remove my downvote... English SE has some funny rules!

Answer (score -1):

This is called a [diphthong](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diphthong). Although the sound does change, it is not treated as separating the word into syllables. Even more exciting is the [triphthong](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/triphthong) where you have three vowel sounds in one syllable!

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Do people disagree with the dictionary (as per my links)?

Comment: I don't agree with downvoting without explanation, but I'd guess it's because, whether or not "fire' includes a triphthong, it *isn't* pronounced "fie-ee-er".  Consider how a foreign learner would use your suggestion  -  the result would sound silly.

Comment: @David - Thanks, I take your point. I've removed the example of "fire".

Answer (score -2):

I hear many people, women more often than men, pronounce these words with two syllables--fie-yer for fire, rue-wool for rule, etc. I think probably most people do it when shouting to somebody far away to achieve greater clarity.  Otherwise it sounds somewhat childlike, but people still do it. NPR reporters seem to prefer these pronunciations.